# CrossOver in Matlab

Tags: matlab

i would like to ask that how to performe CrossOver in Genetic Algorithm using MATLAB.
let us suppose we have the following two sequences,

sequence1 = 1     2     3     7     9    10     5     4     6     8

sequence2 = 4     3     9     2     1     7     6    10     8     5

now i would like to know how to make a code to perform CrossOver in Matlab such that new child sequence is cross-overed  either at a single-point or two-point and the result has no repetition of any number in child sequence.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

With one point crossover you have unique points in range `1..numel(sequence)-1`. To get `n` unique numbers you can use [randperm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html). With two point crossover it will be a bit more difficult, total number of unique combinations will be a sum of arithmetical progression `1..numel(sequence)-2`.

Here is an example of single point crossover:

```
function [result] = CrossoverAtPoint(sequence1, sequence2, point)
    result = [sequence1(1:point-1), sequence2(point:end)];
end

function [result] = CrossoverSinglePoint(sequence1, sequence2, number)
    len = numel(sequence1); % Calculate length
    points = randperm(len-1, number)+1; % Generate set of crossover points in range 2..len
    result = zeros(number, len); % Preallocate matrix
    for i = 1:number
        result(i,:) = CrossoverAtPoint(sequence1, sequence2, points(i));
    end
end

seq1 = [1 2 3 7 9 10 5 4 6 8];
seq2 = [4 3 9 2 1 7 6 10 8 5];
CrossoverSinglePoint(seq1, seq2, 3)
```

The result will be similar to this one:

```
1    2    3    7    9   10    5    4    8    5
1    2    9    2    1    7    6   10    8    5
1    2    3    7    1    7    6   10    8    5
```

---

Update.

This function only guarantees that pivot will be unique for all children. But does not guarantee that children will have all unique elements (this requirement sounds strangely wrong to me), you will have to make a manual check for that.

Comment: i copy it and it gives me error,  >> stack
??? Error: File: stack.m Line: 6 Column: 1
Function definitions are not permitted in this context.

Comment: @asif I don't have matlab right now, but it works in the [octave](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/try_matlab.php). And I can't help you especially without the error you get.

Comment: FUNCTION keyword use  is invalid here.This might cause later message about END.             this error i get when i put the cursor on the Function at line 6.  :(

Comment: and also the child sequence has the numbers that are repeated.  5 is repeated.

Comment: It looks like matlab only allows functions to rest in a separate file.

Comment: still dont work :(  .  is  ur code correct, i mean i don't have to edit anything right ?

Comment: I've checked it in the online octave compiler, link to which I provided before.

Comment: yes i check online on octave.  but again your code have a  weakness,  sometimes numbers are repeated and also sometimes even a number is not present at all in Cross-overed Sequence.   but thanks for the help at least you look at it.

Comment: What you looking for is a permutation, crossover won't feet your needs.